# How to add the Default-Line material back to the LineRenderer material?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If i'm starting with the linerenderer materials and the first place is empty without any material the linerenderer is pink and then i'm trying to add the Default-Line material to the linerenderer in the Start :

```
void Start()
    {
        myLineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        Material defaultLine = new Material(Shader.Find("Default-Line"));
        myLineRenderer.material = defaultLine;
    }
```

but the linerenderer materials is empty.

if i'm trying for example this it will add the Standard material :

```
private Color ggg(Color color)
    {
        Material standrad = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
        standrad.color = Color.red;
        myLineRenderer.material = standrad;
        return color;
    }
```

So why it's not adding the Default-Line ? When adding the Default-Line the materials is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Unity has moved the addresses of the default materials. For default line; Copy the script below:

```cs
    myLineRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Legacy Shaders/Particles/Alpha Blended Premultiply"));
```

---

In fact, you should follow its previous address from `Shader`.

[image]